# Fill-color a county on a map using Python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to figure out how to fill-color each county on a map using Python 2.7.

My assumption is that the border of each county is black and the background can be of any other color.

So, where would I start? Are there modules to ease the task?

Thanks,
R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little late, but I recently put together a guide for this here: http://brandonrose.org/pythonmap

You can download my repo from github and step through it. You'll need to have your own shapefile and dataset though.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I will look into it in the weeks to come (due to personal tight schedule) and I really, really, really appreciate it!